# WPF splash screen with own thread gets dug behind other windows

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, splash-screen

At start of my WPF application I have to load some data. This can take some seconds, so I built a splash screen with a text progress text and a bar. The screen is run by its own thread:

```
public static class SplashScreen
{
     public static void ShowSplash()
     {
         if (_SplashThread == null)
         {
             _SplashThread = new Thread(() =>
                          {
                             _Splash = new WISplash();
                             _Splash.Show();
                             _Splash.Closed += (sender1, e1) => _Splash.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
                             System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
                          });
             _SplashThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
             _SplashThread.IsBackground = true;
             _SplashThread.Start();
         }
     }
}
```

`WISplash`'s base class is `Window`.

**Edit**: I have to state more precisely:
My splash screen does not have the same task bar button. In fact, it has no button at all. I've uploaded a basic project to demonstrate what's happening:
[MyApp.zip](https://rapidshare.com/files/1048118593/MyApp.zip)

Is there a possibility to give the splash screen the same task bar button as the main window?

Comment: Instead of showing the splash on a separate thread, why not load the data on a background thread?

Comment: Sadly, this is no option as the data dictates part of the GUI.

Comment: What do you mean `Bind`?

Comment: If I click in the task bar on my program's icon, I want the splash screen to come to the top.

Comment: If you could create a minimum working example that we could download (Just fill an example main screen with dummy data and use a timer so that it takes awhile) then we may be able to help you better.

Comment: @Norbert: is `ShowDialog(Application.Current.MainWindow)` unacceptable?

Comment: @saunderl: I've specified my problem my precisely.

Comment: @Norbert: I downloaded your demo "MyApp.zip" and run it -I am running on xp sp3 if that matters-. It start -as expected- by showing a window with progress bar that is perform steps every 500 milliseconds and when finished the main window "MyApp" appears, So what is the problem?

Comment: @Jalal Aldeen Saa'd: While seeing the progress bar, you don't see the later task bar button. It's buttonless and I want both the splash screen and the main window to share the same task bar button.

Comment: I agree with Kent, who already noticed that this way of implementing a splash is pretty unusual. Anyway, if you want the progress window to be shown when the application's taskbar button is pressed, you will have to do as sixlettervariables has proposed (use ShowDialog and set the owner window). Only this way you can ensure that the progresswindow will not fall behind the application window.

Comment: Little Mistake there - in WPF ShowDialog has no Parameters. You have to set the Popup's Owner-Property --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not giving the splash window any taskbar button.  When your app gets activated (with event Application.Current.Activated) you can do this:
1) Make the splash window visible
2) Make the splash window topmost (temporarily)
3) Wait for a short time (a few milliseconds)
4) Make the splash window non-topmost
This will make the splash window pop in front of all other windows on activation.

When your app gets deactivated (with events Application.Current.Deactivated or Application.Curent.Exit), make the splash window hidden.

I think that should give you the behavior you are looking for.